# how to return multiple values from a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, return-value, cllocationmanager

I have -(CLLocationCoordinate2D) method, I want to return multiple locations from that method (those locations are using in another method)
my method looks like this,

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation{
 - --------
 ----------
 return location;
 }
```

is it possible to return multiple locations (I mean **return** location1 , **return** location2 . . ..) ?? please help me
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your location objects to an array and return the array instead. e.g.

```
-(NSArray*) addressLocation{
   ...  // Set your locations up
   NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:location1, location2, nil];
   ... // Do any additional processing and return array.
}
```

Comment: is it possible to return an array from CLLocationCoordinate2D method??

Comment: What George is saying is that you need to rewrite your method signature so it returns an Array instead of a CLLocationCoordinate2D.  Then in the method implementation, you should fill an array with coordinates and return those.  Only 1 return will fire, then that method is done.  You cannot do 2 or more returns in the same method call.

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D is not an object. And the code probably will not even compile.

Answer (score 7):

CLLocationCoordinate2D is not an object so they can not just be added to an array and returned. Since they are structs there are a few options,

1. `malloc` an array the old fashion way and copy the struct data into the array
2. `malloc` a new struct pointer, copy the data, then store the pointer in an `NSValue`
3. Create a class that has the same properties as the fields of the struct, and add that to an array

Option 1 and 2 require additional memory management as to when to free the data so avoid those. Option 3 is good and it just so happens MapKit offers the class [`CLLocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html). Here is an example of 2 coordinates.

```
-(NSArray*) addressLocations
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(1.00, 1.00);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(2.00, 2.00);

    CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord1.latitude longitude:coord1.longitude];
    CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord2.latitude longitude:coord2.longitude];

    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:loc1, loc2, nil];

    [loc1 release];
    [loc2 release];

    return array;
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the relevant map kit class to do the work with