# obj-c add c-struct to dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, struct, mapkit

I have trouble to add C-struct to NSDictionary.
The C-struct is MKCoordinateRegion on MapKit.h.

That declaration is

```
typedef struct {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
} MKCoordinateRegion;
```

and CLLocationCoordinate2D's declaration is

```
typedef struct {
    CLLocationDegrees latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude;
} CLLocationCoordinate2D;
```

MKCoordinateSpan is same.

Now, I want add the MKCoordinateRegion to NSDictionary.

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.723128, -74.000694);
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1.0, 1.0);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
    NSMutableDictionary *param = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [param setObject:region forKey:@"region"];
```

5 line has error.
error message is "Sending 'MKCoordinateRegion' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'"

Thanks.

Comment: See the not accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538726/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-method/6539044#6539044). The example is for arrays but the same still applies to dictionaries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't put a struct directly into a dictionary, but you *can* use an `NSValue` to wrap it in such a way that it can be added.

[Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000174-BAJJHDEG):

```
typedef struct { 
  float real; 
  float imaginary; 
} ImaginaryNumber; 

ImaginaryNumber miNumber; 
miNumber.real = 1.1; 
miNumber.imaginary = 1.41; 

NSValue *miValue = [NSValue value: &miNumber 
                        withObjCType:@encode(ImaginaryNumber)]; 

[param setObject:miValue forKey:@"region"];
```

Comment: +1 for a flexible/generic but elegant solution. However Joe's linked answer from his comment constitutes a relevant and specific solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try converting your struct to `NSData`

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&region length:sizeof(MKCoordinateRegion)];
 [param setObject:data forKey:@"region"];
```